# Passing Host Function as a function pointer in __global__ OR __device__ function in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am currently developing a GPU version of a CPU function
(e.g. function Calc(int a, int b, double* c, souble* d, CalcInvFunction GetInv )), in which a host function is passes as a function pointer(e.g. in above example GetInv is the host function of CalcInvFunction type). My question is, if i have to put Calc() function entirely in GPU, i have to pass the GetInv function as a function pointer argument in device function/kernel function, and is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for a GPU implementation of `Calc`,  you should pass the `GetInv` as a `__device__` function pointer.

It is possible, here are some worked examples:

[Ex. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738079/cuda-kernel-with-function-pointer-and-variadic-templates)

[Ex. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002353/function-pointer-to-other-kernel-as-kernel-arg-in-cuda)

[Ex. 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202726/passing-cuda-function-pointers-with-libraries)

Most of the above examples demonstrate bringing the device function pointer *all the way back to the host code*.  This may not be necessary for your particular case.  But it should be fairly obvious from above how to grab a `__device__` function pointer (in device code) and use it in a kernel.

Comment: [Yet another worked example of function pointer usage in device code](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/457094/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-can-i-use-__device__-function-pointer-in-cuda-/post/3247854/#3247854)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000388/device-function-pointers) is another example.

Comment: And [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879789/thrust-transform-throws-error-bulk-kernel-by-value-an-illegal-memory-access-w) using templating.

Comment: [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872882/passing-intrinsic-function-as-template-parameter) templating example

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i have been able to pass a host function as a function pointer in cuda kernel function (__global__ function). Thanks to Robert Crovella and njuffa for the answer. I have been able to pass a class member function(cpu function) as a function pointer to a cuda kernel. But, the main problem is, i can only pass the static class member function. I am not being able to pass the function not declared as static.
For Example:

`/**/
  __host__ __device__ 
  static int 
      CellfunPtr(
      void*ptr, int a
  );
  /**/`

The above function work because this member function is declared as static member function. If i do not declare this member function as a static member as ,
    `/**/
  __host__ __device__ 
  int 
      CellfunPtr(
      void*ptr, int a
  );
  /**/`

then it doesnt work.

The complete code has four files.

---

1. First file

`/*start of fundef.h file*/`

`typedef int (*pFunc_t)(void* ptr, int N);`

`/*end of fundef.h file*/`

---

2. Second file

`/*start of solver.h file*/`

```
    class CalcVars {

       int eqnCount;
       int numCell;                      
       int numTri;
       int numTet;

    public:
       double* cellVel; 
       double* cellPre;

    /** Constructor */

    CalcVars(
        const int eqnCount_,             
        const int numCell_,          
        const int numTri_,             
        const int numTet_                
    );

    /** Destructor */

    ~CalcVars(void);

    public:

      void 
          CalcAdv();


      __host__ __device__ 
      static int 
          CellfunPtr(
          void*ptr, int a
    );

    };
```

`/*end of solver.h file*/`

---

3. Third file

`/*start of solver.cu file*/`

```
     #include "solver.h"
     __device__ pFunc_t pF1_d = CalcVars::CellfunPtr;

    pFunc_t pF1_h ;


    __global__ void kernel(int*a, pFunc_t func, void* thisPtr_){
        int tid = threadIdx.x;
        a[tid] = (*func)(thisPtr_, a[tid]); 
    };

    /* Constructor */

    CalcVars::CalcVars(
        const int eqnCount_,             
        const int numCell_,          
        const int numTri_,             
        const int numTet_   

    )
    {
        this->eqnCount = eqnCount_;
        this->numCell = numCell_;
        this->numTri = numTri_;

        this->cellVel = (double*) calloc((size_t) eqnCount, sizeof(double)); 
        this->cellPre = (double*) calloc((size_t) eqnCount, sizeof(double)); 

    }

    /* Destructor */

    CalcVars::~CalcVars(void)
    {
       free(this->cellVel);
       free(this->cellPre);

    }


    void 
    CalcVars::CalcAdv(
    ){

        /*int b1 = 0;

        b1 = CellfunPtr(this, 1);*/

       int Num = 50;
       int *a1, *a1_dev;

        a1 = (int *)malloc(Num*sizeof(int));

        cudaMalloc((void**)&a1_dev, Num*sizeof(int));

        for(int i = 0; i <Num; i++){
            a1[i] = i;
        }

        cudaMemcpy(a1_dev, a1, Num*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        //copy addresses of device functions to host 
        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&pF1_h, pF1_d, sizeof(pFunc_t));


        kernel<<<1,42>>>(a1_dev, pF1_h, this);

        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        cudaMemcpy(a1, a1_dev, Num*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    };


    int 
    CalcVars::CellfunPtr(
        void* ptr, int a
    ){
        //CalcVars* ClsPtr = (CalcVars*)ptr;
        printf("Printing from CPU function\n");
        //int eqn_size = ClsPtr->eqnCount;
        //printf("The number is %d",eqn_size);
        return a-1;

    };
```

`/*end of solver.cu file*/`

---

4. Fourth file

`/*start of main.cpp file*/`

```
    #include "solver.h"


    int main(){

        int n_Eqn, n_cell, n_tri, n_tetra;
        n_Eqn = 100;
        n_cell = 200;
        n_tri = 300;
        n_tetra = 400;

       CalcVars* calcvars;

       calcvars = new CalcVars(n_Eqn, n_cell, n_tri, n_tetra );

       calcvars->CalcAdv();

       system("pause");

    }
```

`/*end of main.cpp file*/`