# passing intrinsic function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I'm trying to passing atomicAdd function into another function as template parameter.

Here is my Kernel1:

```
template<typename T, typename TAtomic>
__global__ void myfunc1(T *address, TAtomic atomicFunc) {
    atomicFunc(address, 1);
}
```

**Try 1:**

```
myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(val.dev_ptr, atomicAdd);
```

It does not work due to the compiler cannot match the expected function signature.

**Try 2:**
Firstly, I wrap the atomicAdd into a custom function called MyAtomicAdd.

```
template<typename T>
__device__ void MyAtomicAdd(T *address, T val) {
    atomicAdd(address, val);
}
```

Then, I defined a function pointer called "TAtomic" and declare the TAtomic as template parameter.

```
typedef void (*TAtomic)(float *,float);

template<typename T, TAtomic atomicFunc>
__global__ void myfunc2(T *address) {
    atomicFunc(address, 1);
}

myfunc2<float, MyAtomicAdd><<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr);
CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

Actually, Try 2 works. But, I don't want to use typedef. I need something more generic.

**Try 3:**
Just passing MyAtomicAdd to myfunc1.

```
myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr, MyAtomicAdd<float>);
CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

**The compiler can compile the code. But when I run the program, a error reported:**

```
"ERROR in /home/liang/groute-dev/samples/framework/pagerank.cu:70: invalid program counter (76)"
```

I just wondering, why try 3 doesn't work? And any simple or gentle way exists to implement this requirement? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 3 doesn't work because you are attempting to take the address of a `__device__` function in host code, which is illegal in CUDA:

```
myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr, MyAtomicAdd<float>);
                          ^
                          effectively a function pointer - address of a __device__ function
```

Such usage attempts in CUDA will resolve to some sort of an "address" - but it is garbage, so when you try to use it as an actual function entry point in device code, you get the error you encountered: `invalid program counter` (or in some cases, just `illegal address`).

You can make your Try 3 method work (without a `typedef`) by wrapping the intrinsic in a functor instead of a bare `__device__` function:

```
$ cat t48.cu
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
__device__ void MyAtomicAdd(T *address, T val) {
    atomicAdd(address, val);
}


template <typename T>
struct myatomicadd
{
  __device__ T operator()(T *addr, T val){
    return atomicAdd(addr, val);
  }
};

template<typename T, typename TAtomic>
__global__ void myfunc1(T *address, TAtomic atomicFunc) {
    atomicFunc(address, (T)1);
}


int main(){

  int *dev_ptr;
  cudaMalloc(&dev_ptr, sizeof(int));
  cudaMemset(dev_ptr, 0, sizeof(int));
//  myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr, MyAtomicAdd<int>);
  myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr, myatomicadd<int>());
  int h = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(&h, dev_ptr, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("h = %d\n", h);
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t48 t48.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t48
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
h = 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

We can realize a slightly simpler version of this as well, letting the functor template type be inferred from the kernel template type:

```
$ cat t48.cu
#include <stdio.h>

struct myatomicadd
{
template <typename T>
  __device__ T operator()(T *addr, T val){
    return atomicAdd(addr, val);
  }
};

template<typename T, typename TAtomic>
__global__ void myfunc1(T *address, TAtomic atomicFunc) {
    atomicFunc(address, (T)1);
}


int main(){

  int *dev_ptr;
  cudaMalloc(&dev_ptr, sizeof(int));
  cudaMemset(dev_ptr, 0, sizeof(int));
  myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptr, myatomicadd());
  int h = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(&h, dev_ptr, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("h = %d\n", h);
  float *dev_ptrf;
  cudaMalloc(&dev_ptrf, sizeof(float));
  cudaMemset(dev_ptrf, 0, sizeof(float));
  myfunc1<<<1,1>>>(dev_ptrf, myatomicadd());
  float hf = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(&hf, dev_ptrf, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("hf = %f\n", hf);
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t48 t48.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t48
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
h = 1
hf = 1.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

More treatments of the use of device function pointers in CUDA are linked to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057870/passing-host-function-as-a-function-pointer-in-global-or-device-function/31058123#31058123).

Comment: I wonder... could this wrapper be generalized through templates, so that a single wrapper is used for all device-side functions? i.e. with `template <typename F, typename... Ts>` ?